# Swiftui Scrollview scroll to bottom of list

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview

I'm trying to make my view scroll to the bottom of the item list every time a new item is added.
This is my code, can someone help please?

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ScrollViewReader{ value in
                    VStack() {
                        ForEach(0..<self.count, id:\.self) {
                            Text("item \($0)")
                        }
                    }.onChange(of: self.data.sampleCount, perform: value.scrollTo(-1))
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add an EmptyView item in the bottom of list

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ScrollViewReader{ value in
                VStack() {
                    ForEach(0..<self.count, id:\.self) {
                        Text("item \($0)")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                        .id("anID") //You can use any type of value 
                }.onChange(of: self.data.sampleCount, perform: { count in
                   value.scrollTo("anID")
            })
        }
```

Comment: I've used it this way  
````Spacer().id(names.count)````

so that I can use 

    onChange(of: int) { _ in
        value.scrollTo(names.count)
    }

Answer (score 4):

We need to give `id` for views which in `ScrollView` we want to scroll to.

Here is a demo of solution. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    
    @State private var data = [String]()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add") { data.append("Data \(data.count + 1)")}
                .padding().border(Color.blue)
                
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ScrollViewReader{ sr in
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(self.data.indices, id:\.self) {
                            Text("item \($0)")
                                .padding().id($0)     // << give id
                        }
                    }.onChange(of: self.data.count) { count in
                        withAnimation {
                            sr.scrollTo(count - 1)   // << scroll to view with id
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about ios13?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example/solution.

```
var scrollView : some View {
     ScrollView(.vertical) {
       ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
         ForEach(self.messagesStore.messages) { msg in
           VStack {
             OutgoingPlainMessageView() {
               Text(msg.message).padding(.all, 20)
                 .foregroundColor(Color.textColorPrimary)
                 .background(Color.colorPrimary)
             }.listRowBackground(Color.backgroundColorList)
             Spacer()
           }
           // 1. First important thing is to use .id 
           //as identity of the view
           .id(msg.id)
           .padding(.leading, 10).padding(.trailing, 10)
    }
    // 2. Second important thing is that we are going to implement //onChange closure for scrollTarget change, 
    //and scroll to last message id
    .onChange(of: scrollTarget) { target in
        withAnimation {
            scrollView.scrollTo(target, anchor: .bottom)
        }
    }
    // 3. Third important thing is that we are going to implement //onChange closure for keyboardHeight change, and scroll to same //scrollTarget to bottom.
    .onChange(of: keyboardHeight){ target in
       if(nil != scrollTarget){
       withAnimation {
       scrollView.scrollTo(scrollTarget, anchor: .bottom)
       }
      }
    }
    //4. Last thing is to add onReceive clojure, that will add an action to perform when this ScrollView detects data emitted by the given publisher, in our case messages array.
    // This is the place where our scrollTarget is updating.
    .onReceive(self.messagesStore.$messages) { messages in
        scrollView.scrollTo(messages.last!.id, anchor: .bottom)
        self.scrollTarget = messages.last!.id
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

Also take a look at my article on medium.

https://mehobega.medium.com/auto-scrollview-using-swiftui-and-combine-framework-b3e40bb1a99f